# ActiveX control calls vba userform with an argument

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of simple activeX buttons which will should show me a form I have defined in slightly different manner. Sample code bellow:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Matryca.Show
End Sub
```

Now I have those controls in various positions and when I call a form I want to pass a different argument contingent on which button was clicked. If `CommandButton1` has been clicked then I want my form to show argument number 1 in the corner if `CommandButton2`  I want i show number 2 and so forth..

How to pass arguments to a form I am calling? Any more ideas?

Comment: Simple method is to add a public variable to the form (or use a Property procedure to do it properly), then `Load` the form, set the variable and then `Show` the form.

Comment: Use Click Event, for example `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` and inside this `Sub` put all instructions, which You described. Use your `TextBox` or `Frame` property `Caption` to show values according to CommandButtons.

Comment: But my activeX control is located on the worksheet not on the form thus I am trying to launch a form from a worksheet.